# Stop function execution is input element has focus?

Tags: jquery

I haven't been able to find a good answer to this issue. I'm trying to get a better handle on some nicer looking/acting form elements with JQuery. Here's the code I'm using so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.input').addClass('inputOut clear'); // Grey out text initially, default bg

        $('.input').each(function() { // Fill in form fields with labels
            var text = getAttr($(this));
            $(this).attr("value", text);
            $(this).hasfocus = false;
        });

        $('.input').mouseover(function() {
            if ($(this).hasfocus == true) return;
            else {
                var text = getAttr($(this));
                $(this).removeClass();
                if($(this).attr("value") == text) $(this).addClass('inputOver clear');
                else $(this).addClass('inputOver filled');
            }
        });

        $('.input').mouseout(function() {
            if ($(this).hasfocus == true) return;
            else {
                var text = getAttr($(this));
                $(this).removeClass();
                if(($(this).attr("value") == "") || ($(this).attr("value") == text)) $(this).addClass('inputOut clear');
                else $(this).addClass('inputOut filled');
            }
        });

        $('.input').focus(function() {
            $(this).hasfocus = true;
            $(this).removeClass();
            $(this).addClass('inputActive');
            var text = getAttr($(this));
            if($(this).attr("value") == text) {
                $(this).attr("value", "");
            }
        });

        $('.input').blur(function() {
            $(this).hasfocus = false;
            var text = getAttr($(this));
            $(this).removeClass();
            if($(this).attr("value") == "") {
                $(this).attr("value", text);
                $(this).addClass('inputOut clear');
            }
            else if(($(this).attr("value") != "") && ($(this).attr("value") != text)) {
                $(this).addClass('inputOut filled');
            }
        });

        // TEST SPANS
        $("#spans span.off").fadeIn(0);

    });

    function getAttr(element) {
        var text = element.attr("id");
        text = text.replace(/-/g," ");
        return text;
    }
```

Everything is working exactly as I'd like except for one thing. The mouseover/mouseout functions run on elements that have focus. Being mostly HTML/PHP, my Javascript skills are definitely a work in progress, so be nice. What I thought would work is to add a isFocused property (you can see what I tried in there),  but it hasn't worked as I've tried it so far.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: tip: If You make an example on jsfiddle or something like that it will make more people willing to try and fix Your script

Comment: Whoa, this site is amazing! Hadn't heard of this.

Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/Cjjv8/9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to refactor a bit.

Create named functions, or [better]create an object (global is ok if You don't have a lot of js out there) and put Your functions in that object so that they have names.

```
MyAwesomeGlobalSomething={};
MyAwesomeGlobalSomething.mOverFunc=function(){
  //the stuff You do
       if ($(this).hasfocus == true) return;
            else {
                var text = getAttr($(this));
                $(this).removeClass();
                if($(this).attr("value") == text) $(this).addClass('inputOver clear');
                else $(this).addClass('inputOver filled');
            }
}
//and more functions here
```

You can now bind

```
 $('.input').mouseover(MyAwesomeGlobalSomething.mOverFunc);
```

now

```
$('.input').focus(function(){
  $(this).unbind('mouseover');
//and more functions here
});
```

fixes Your problem and

```
$('.input').blur(function(){
  $(this).mouseover(MyAwesomeGlobalSomething.mOverFunc);
//and more functions here
});
```

returns the function binding

Comment: I'm going to give this a whirl. Nice description. Being that JS isn't a true OO language, JS objects have tripped me up so far. The Flanagan book doesn't do too great of a job explaning it but this might get me going down the right road. 

I was planning on making all of this a plugin (using CSS3 gradients rather than the images). How would using objects work in that case, and what is the alternative to global objects considering this will eventually be used in many different instances?

Comment: JS is based on Prototyping idea. You can inherit from objects not classes and add methods on the fly - that's the basic of basics of that concept. If you are creating a plugin I'd recommend putting the object in jquery.pluginname namespace. Read about plugin authoring and It's there somewhere. Feel free to ask if not satisfied ;) I enjoy introducing people representing ambitious approach

Comment: Hey naugtur, here's what I've come up with (which works fine so far! also have moved to CSS3 properties rather than images [interestingly enough I had to force border color changes by .css(). Weird!]): http://jsfiddle.net/uVDQP/3 -- Now, I'd like to refactor this a little further before I build it into a plugin. I tried (and failed), but I'd like to make the TextInput object (and in turn the subsequent objects that will handle the other form field types) into a constructor object with all the stuff going on in the jQuery "each" statement happening automatically with the "new" instantiation.

Comment: As interesting as it sounds (moreover - I did some OO-style things in JS+jQuery) I'd recommend creating an `unobtrusive` plugin that would transform a simple input into this cool looking one with such a code: `$('.myinput').makeItLookAwesome();`  Start the plugin from this template: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Putting_It_All_Together

Comment: I did a mockup (not correct code yet, boot it's how it should look) http://jsfiddle.net/dtFq4/2/

Answer (score 0):

I think you want line 7:

```
$(this).isFocused == "false";
```

to be

```
$(this).isFocused = "false";
```

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct on that, however that's not going to be what the overall problem is.

Comment: You'll also want to use the keywords `true` and `false` instead of the string values that you have.

Comment: With PHP I'm used to the string values (or for me, I prefer 0's and 1's). Tried that as well to no avail, but good to know they are actually key words.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following would probably evaluate the same in this instance, but shouldnt:

`if ($(this).hasfocus == "true") return;`

be:

`if ($(this).hasfocus == true) return;`